# Creating Multiple Entities during Registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework and the Identity. I have three entities that I need to create at the time of Registration : the standard ApplicationUser, Person, Business.The following are my definitions:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
  public GUID ID {get; set}
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
  public System.DateTime? BirthDate{get; set;}
  public string email {get;set;}

  //ForeignKeys
  public virtual Business Manager {get; set;}
  public virtual Business Executive {get; set;}
  public virtual Business Employees {get; set;}
}

public class Business
{
  public Guid ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Registrtion {get; set;}

  //Collections
  public ICollection<Person> Managers {get;set;}
  public ICollection<Person> Executives {get; set;}
  public ICollection<Person> Employees {get; set;}

  public Business()
  {
    this.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string BusinesName {get; set}
    public person Owner {get; set;}
    Managers= new List<Person>();
    Executives = new List<Person>();
    Employees = new List<Person>();
  }
}
```

I have a registration page, where the user can select to register as a Solo or as a Business. My Method is as below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    Business business;
    var user = new ApplicationUser
    {
      UserName = model.Email,
      Email = model.Email,
      Person = new Person
      {               
        FirstName = model.FirstName,
        LastName = model.LastName,
        Landline = model.Landline,
        emailAddress = model.Email
      }
    };

    //I'm then checking the model fields to see if they need to be setup as a Busines or not. 
    if (model.createBusinessAccount)
    {
      business = new Business
      {
        BusinessName = model.BusinessName,
        Owner = person
      };
      business.Members.Add(person);
      person.Business = business;
      db.Businesses.Add(business);
    }
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
      await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
      db.SaveChanges(); //<<<<<I get an error at this step. 
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    AddErrors(result);
  }
  // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
  return View(model);
}//End
```

I'm getting an error :

> The property 'ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Although I'm not modifying any ID apart from generating a key for the BUsiness Entity. 
Do I need the db.SaveChanges(); ? I'm assuming that I need this, without this the db.Businesses.Add(business); is not reflected in the DB.I'm also assuming that the await Usermanager.Createasync is also commiting to the DB (but the business entity is not being stored.

Comment: could it be because of `this.ID = Guid.NewGuid();`? in your `Business` class?

Comment: I had to put that in to generate the guid, are you suggesting to use GUIDs from the database ?

Comment: If you need to generate Id from your c#, try decorating the Id field with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`

Comment: I've just tried it using [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] and no luck, same error at the same place.

Comment: I've been hacking away with this, and it seems to work partially if I use a new context. However, I need to take the registered user.person and add it to Business.People.Add... when I do this it is trying to create a new entity for user.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you'd have to generate id yourself rather than let database do that?

Comment: Also are you using codefirst or existing database with EF?

Comment: Hi Tomi, that shouldn't be a problem yeah ? I thought it is easier for me to control in the C# layer. But this doesn't have a problem if I create a new Database context e.g ApplicationDbContext newdb = new ApplicationDbContext(); and it inserts it properly as long as I don't add the existing logged in user to the Business.People List.